# Typescript Why this recursive map type does not satisfy the constraint?

Tags: typescript

```
type RecursiveMap<
    A extends Record<string, unknown>,
    B extends Record<string, unknown>
> = {
    [K in keyof A]: K extends keyof B
        ? A[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
            ? B[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
                ? RecursiveMap<A[K], B[K]>
                : never
            : never
        : never
}
```

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIFkCGYAPAFACQAglBAB7AQB2AJqrAgPbKOGrDLr0BzADRRE9ANb02Ad3oA%20IWQBCVWg2at4HLjz6CRYyTPnE5UALxQA3mQDaAaSj8o4iCDYAzKOQC6ALihHGjomFld3LyUyUgB%20bwcfVRCNOC1Obl5%20YVEJKVk5aNioJQSk9RZU7Qy9bMM8k1JGotSUDGx8InIEkRL7HwKm0gD6CGxkQuHRiHHGybHiAF9iIA)

why `A[K]` does not satisfy the constraint? I have already checked it with `A[K] extends Record<string, unknown>`, how is this make sense?

Comment: @ShreekeshMurkar - In the above, `A[K]` is `unknown`, not `string`, and that's what the OP is trying to narrow with the conditionals. (**`K`** will be `string`, not `A[K]`.) (Also: I recommend not saying "This is wrong !!" It comes across as very negative. :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a bug in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#45651](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45651).  Apparently in TS4.5 and below, this kind of [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) check on an [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) doesn't always properly constrain the type in the true branch.  Luckily this bug was fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#47791](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47791) which should be part of the upcoming TS4.6 release, the release candidate version of which you can use right now as `4.6.1-rc`:

```
type RecursiveMap<
    A extends Record<string, unknown>,
    B extends Record<string, unknown>
> = {
    [K in keyof A]: K extends keyof B
        ? A[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
            ? B[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
                ? RecursiveMap<A[K], B[K]> // okay
                : never
            : never
        : never
}
```

[Playground link to 4.6.1-rc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.1-rc#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIFkCGYAPALABQUFUAglBAB7AQB2AJqrAgPbIuGrDJ0TAOYAaKIiYBrJpwDuTAHyiylKACFaDZmw7xuvfoJHjJM+UrKKoAXigBvVZQDaAaShCoUiCE4AzagBdAC4od3pGVnZvXwD1JzUKAH5qN0CtSN04fR4+ASExCWlZBUUExLUU9TSMnXZsgzzjQrMSy3IKzuS9FAxsfCIqNPFq10DrAHoJqE4pPBByrrVQpghsZEXOlbWIDY6K7fWyAF8gA)

If you can't wait for the fix version, you can work around it with an off-label use of [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).  If you have a type `T` that you know is assignable to a type `U` but the compiler doesn't, you can replace `U` with `Extract<T, U>` and fix the problem.  As long as you are correct about `T` and `U`, then later `Extract<T, U>` will evaluate to `T` (if you're wrong then it will evaluate so something closer to `T & U` which may be `never` so be careful):

```
type RecursiveMap<
    A extends Record<string, unknown>,
    B extends Record<string, unknown>
    > = {
        [K in keyof A]: K extends keyof B
        ? A[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
        ? B[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
        ? RecursiveMap<
            Extract<A[K], Record<string, unknown>>,
            Extract<B[K], Record<string, unknown>>
        >
        : never
        : never
        : never
    }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDcIFkCGYAPALABQUFUAglBAB7AQB2AJqrAgPbIuGrDJ0TAOYAaKIiYBrJpwDuTAHyiylKACFaDZmw7xuvfoJHjJM+UtWVFUALxQA3lbUUA2gGkoQqFIghOAGbUALoAXFCe9Iys7L7+QerOLgD81B7BWtG6cPo8fAJCYhLSsgqKSWqp6umZOuw5BvnGRWalluQuFKk5KBjY+EQVnVAAogzIePDAhFTp4g15RoWmJRaKykOdYwKT09XuwfNciwUmxeZl5R2dV8NQ4UwQ2Mib91CPz68PTxAv11AAXzIZCAA)